# Is it possible for my Mac Mini to heat up because of wrong RAM frequency?

Tags: macos, mac, memory

I have a Mac Mini (Mid 2010) which supports RAM speed 1066MHz.
I replaced a year ago the 2x1gb default RAMs with a 4gb at 1333MHz. It worked but I noticed that it became slower and started to heat up only with Firefox open.

So is there a possibility that the RAM is affecting the system?

I read many posts about this but I didn't get my question answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer**: yes.

**Long Answer**:

The Mid 2010 Mac Mini was not officially rated to support 1333Mhz, but depending on the motherboard provided, the system may attempt to adapt if the BIOS and hardware supports this.

This means that the system will most likely increase it's power consumption, causing possible heat-up and failure of parts.